# Why is the generated binary static ELF executable so large for an asm Hello World using system calls directly?

Tags: assembly, linker, executable, ld, elf

Here's the hello world program in AT&T assembly:

```
.global _start

.text
_start:
        movl  $4, %eax
        movl  $1, %ebx
        movl  $msg, %ecx
        movl  $len, %edx
        int   $0x80

        movl  $1, %eax
        movl  $0, %ebx
        int   $0x80
.data
msg:
        .ascii  "Hello, world!\n"
        len =   . - msg
```

After I assembled and link it with these commands: `as hello.S -o hello.o && ld hello.o -o hello`, I saw the `hello` binary is almost 9 kB large! When I took a look at its hexadump, it's almost just 0s. Why is that (I have a x86_64 machine)?

Comment: Most of it is padding for page alignment so read/write `.data` initial values don't get mapped as part of executable `.text`.  Older `ld` used to be different, but I think this recent change reduces exposure of non-code as potential "gadgets" for ROP and spectre attacks.  Note that `strip` will remove a bit of stuff.  See also https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html.

Comment: Also note that using 32-bit int 0x80 in 64-bit code is not good, and that you could put your string in `.rodata` so it can maybe go in the same ELF segment as your `.text` section, although I think recent `ld` will separate them so `.rodata` can be non-executable.  BTW, FASM can make very small executables; it generates executables directly instead of letting `ld` do it, and leaves out ELF section headers, emitting *only* ELF program headers that let the OS load it.  (This isn't exactly an answer, so I'm only posting comments)

Comment: There's a lot of metadata in that.  Use the `size` utility too see how much of that is your actual program.

Comment: @fuz: most of it is padding, not metadata.  Like 8.9k before `strip`, 8.4k after.  gzips down to 349 bytes so the actual information content is low (again, big runs of zeros for padding, not metadata)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517571/why-does-compiling-this-simple-assembly-code-and-linking-to-elf-result-in-such-a